# Why does 'sudo pwd' work but not 'sudo cd'?

Tags: command-line, sudo

Many of the StackOverflow answers suggest that it is because `cd` is a builtin, but `type cd` and `type pwd` both return "shell builtin" and only `sudo cd` returns a "command not found".

So is `cd` handled as a special case contrary to many answers on SO which is "`sudo` only works with programs"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pwd` exists as both a shell builtin (which is why `type pwd` returns that it is a shell builtin) and separately as a **GNU Core Utility**. 
The version of `pwd` that your system is using is the [GNU Core Utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) version. It is a executable and as such sudo can be used to run it; unlike `cd` which is a shell builtin command.

You can verify this for yourself.

Type both these commands youself and observe the outcomes. (if there are multiple versions of the same command in your system the `which` command will tell you which one is being invoked when you enter it)

```
which pwd

which cd
```

A shell builtin will return no folder path to an executable when you run the `which` command.
Here are example outputs of both commands on my system:

```
nate@linux:~> which pwd  
/usr/bin/pwd


nate@linux:~> which cd
which: no cd in (/home/nate/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/home/nate/Scripts:/home/nate/Scripts)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `pwd` executable somewhere (try `whereis pwd`) and `sudo` uses it.